# How to run Ant inside Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ant

I'm wondering if anyone out there has any ideas about how to run Ant inside Visual Studio 2008. I'm looking to perform some pretty common Ant tasks such as selecting a target to run inside a build file.

I have come across and am aware of NANT as well as MSBUILD as more preferred build tools for ASP.NET projects, but I am only interested in some ideas about running Ant within the IDE.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a quick and dirty solution you could add it using the *External Tools...* option in the Tools menu.

You can then see the Ant output in the Output window, and you can pass it various things like the current Project directory on the command line.

You can also assign keyboard shortcuts to the `Tools.ExternalCommandXX` commands which represent the external tools in the Tools menu.

Comment: Ok. That is one option, and maybe the only one out there. But, ideally I would like something a little fancier. Maybe some kind of plugin for that would give me some type of GUI interface to select targets to run in my build file.

Comment: I went the route of adding external tools to run Ant. It works. If anyone has a better solution, I would love to hear about it.