# How to fire a build from visual studio 2010 using ant?

Tags: visual-studio, ant

I want to automatically build my project using ant.
Each and every time I am doing it manually.

Can any one please tell me how to start a build using ant in visual studio 2010?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757273/how-to-run-ant-inside-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have done using the command prompt .

`TFSBuild start /collection:"http://milagan2008svr:8080/" /builddefinition:"EvolveNET 2010\EvolveNET" /droplocation:"\\milagan2008svr\Builds\EvolveNET 2010" /priority:"High"  /login:usr,passwd`

So with ant i used `<exec>` of ant command to fire a build. This solved my problem :)